# Geometry node : issue? using capture position attribute to set a Mesline starting points

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to draw curve between 2 vertices of a mesh.
For that I try to Use Attribute Capture with Position, and use for set start and end position of a mesh line... but it doesn't work as shown in the images below. Any help welcome.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: something like the diagram below... [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jk3W.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jk3W.png) a related question : how to control the start en end position of a bezier segment? do I have to use instance on point with a bezier segment as instance?

Answer (score 2):

Nodes spawning meshes require constant values - their sockets are circular. What you're connecting, are fields - their sockets are in diamond shape.

If you have some programming skills, passing a field into a circular socket is as correct as passing a function, where a value is expected instead...

I see what you're going for by deleting geometry twice, rather than just once with *Compare to 0.5, Epsillon 0.6* or *Equal 0 OR Equal 1*. This way you have two geometries, each with just a single point - so the nodes could just pass a single value rather than a field (and maybe it will work this way in the future, who knows).

Instead of *Capture Attribute*, you can use an *Attribute Statistic* node:

[image]

And since it allows you to **select** stuff, you don't need to delete geometry:

[image]

Or You can use *Set Position* node to set the correct positions after the *Mesh Line* is spawned. It accepts fields, so you can use *Transfer Attribute* node in *Index* mode - and you don't even need to translate indices in your case:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Markus for your time  and the 3 solutions that help me a lot... It's not very obvious to well understand the geom node from documentation. Do you know where I could find more detailed doc about geo node? Cheers

Comment: @NetCob [Robin Betts' answers tagged geonodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A35559+%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D), or [Official Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html) also there's many new nodes available in 3.1, e.g. [Edge Neighbors Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/edge_neighbors.html), there's a [Blender Discord Server](https://discord.gg/blender) which has a channel `#help-geonodes`, and many youtube tutorials. More educational content than you can ever consume 

Comment: Hello again, If you want, can you help for this use case : I want to start with a geometry, for instance like an UV Sphere, and I want to pick randomly couple of its vertice to create bezier segment for each couple...